# Finding the magnitude of the vector OP

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Three points join together to for a triangle, $A(-3,4)$ $B(2,5)$ and $O(0,0)$. Between the points $A$ and $B$ there is a point $P$ this point is in a ratio of $t:1-t$. Find the magnitude of $OP$.

$OP=OA+AP$. Finding the magnitude of $AB= (-3,4)-(2,5)$ which makes $(-5,1)$ using that I said that $-3,4 + t/1(-5,1)$ which then makes $(-3(5t),4+t)$

Comment: Need to find the parametric equation for a moving point P connected to O

Comment: OP=OA+AP. Finding the magnitude of AB= (-3,4)-(2,5) which makes (-5,1) using that I said that -3,4 + t/1(-5,1) which then makes (-3(5t),4+t)

Comment: Note that in bezier's curve 0<_t _<1